# react-bootstrap Form.File specify multiple allowed files formats

Tags: html, input, react-bootstrap

I want to restrict users to only upload images of certain formats. For this, I want to pass multiple file types in the `accept` prop of Form.File. I can only find examples with one file type only. Below is my code so far:

```
<InputGroup >
    <Form.Group>
        <Form.File 
         onChange={(e) => setGamePhoto(e.target.files[0])}
         label="Upload The End-Game Photo"
         accept=".png"
        />
   </Form.Group>
</InputGroup>
```

I want to pass multiple file types like png, jpg, jpeg, web etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert it in the form of a comma `,` separated list. Try this:

```
<InputGroup >
    <Form.Group>
        <Form.File 
         onChange={(e) => setGamePhoto(e.target.files[0])}
         label="Upload The End-Game Photo"
         accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.webp"
        />
   </Form.Group>
</InputGroup>
```